# 3 Columns on Desktop to 2 Columns on Tablet

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 and am trying to display multiple rows, each containing 3 boxes. All boxes are the same size so it is very uniform. You can picture it as a grid. On a tablet I want only two columns.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> Uniform box of content here </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> Uniform box of content here </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> Uniform box of content here </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> Uniform box of content here </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> Uniform box of content here </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> Uniform box of content here </div>
</div>
```

Now, this works great on my desktop. And on a mobile device they all collapse into one single column as desired. On a tablet, they all fall into two cloumns. However, the issue is that I have an uneven number of columns dividing into an even number of columns. This leaves a row of 2, followed by a row of 1. Then the next row creates a row of 2 followed by a row of 1.

Is there any simple way to make the next row "pop up" to complete rows of two columns on a tablet while maintaining 3 columns on a desktop? As it stands I have empty columns in every-other-row on my tablet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't put them into separate rows and it should behave the way you described...

```
<div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> Uniform box of content here </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> Uniform box of content here </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> Uniform box of content here </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> Uniform box of content here </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> Uniform box of content here </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> Uniform box of content here </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/gmU7w/

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Wasn't sure it was valid for a row to be greater than 12, but it just pushes it below as expected.

Comment: @BrandonSmith One way to think of it is like a paragraph and each div is a word. Each word has certain number of width units assigned and only 12 units can fit on a line. If div doesn't fit on the current "line" it "wraps" to the next line. In the above example, each div is 4 units wide on screens medium and larger (so it forms into 2 lines of 3), 6 wide on small screens (3 lines of 2), and (because no units are defined) 12 wide on x-small (6 lines of 1). The outer div you can think of as the paragraph itself. Not sure if that helps at all but that's how I think about BS3's grid system. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the "Mixed width columns" section at http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-grid-introduction